# How to solve an integral with another function of x in power?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I am working on an equation in economics and was able to combine two different equations and got the following equation:
$$\dfrac{a\cdot\left(1-\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^{\operatorname{t}\left(x\right)}\right)}{x^b}$$
Where t(x) is another function and c and a are constants. What would the antiderivative of the equation be.

Context:
This equation represents the demand curve of a product if the product is given the time t(x) on the market. I need to find the equation that tells the total  sales the product would make over changing both the price and the time given. The x represents quantity demanded while t(x) represents the time it is given on the market when x is the demanded quantity for the price the company is selling at the time. The area under the demand graph would tell me the the total profit. Also, I would appreciate any suggestions to what t(x) should be where the area under the graph of t(x) is the minimum and the area under the demand graph is the maximum for any two points on the x axis.

Edit:
I didn't define the function t(x) and realized that it is important to define it to solve it in the comments. While the equation requires t(x) to be ambiguous, t(x) may be defined as:
$$\dfrac{e}{x^d}$$
Where both e and d are constants.

Comment: The question is incomplete as is. Please add in the details of the question, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: You really should give more details about the question, and the function $t(x)$ in particular. Without this information, it is difficult, or impossible, to solve the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really solve the integral, because an unsolved function $t(x)$ is present. The closest you can get to is
$$\int{\frac{a\left(1-\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^{t(x)}\right)}{x^b}\ \mathrm{d}x}$$
$$=a\left(\int{\frac{1}{x^b}\ \mathrm{d}x}-\int{\frac{\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^{t(x)}}{x^b}\ \mathrm{d}x}\right)$$
$$=a\left(\frac{x^{1-b}}{1-b}-\int{\frac{\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^{t(x)}}{x^b}\ \mathrm{d}x}\right)$$
assuming that $b\ne1$. I don't think you can get any further without specifying what $t(x)$ is.

Edit: Here is my edited answer to your edited question. Note that I replaced $e$ with $\epsilon$ to avoid ambiguity with the mathematical constant $e$ should I ever need it.

I am no expert in economics, so here is the answer I can currently provide:

First of all, the expression may very well be imaginary for some choices of values, so you need to specify the range of the constants to avoid that, but that's more of a nitpick.

Second of all, I inputted the integral where all of $b,c,d,\epsilon=1$ into WolframAlpha. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%291-x%5C%2841%29%2CDivide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5D%2Cx%5D%2Cx%5D

Well, there is no elementary antiderivative. So I guess you can't even evaluate the 'simplest' antiderivative of this. But what you can do, is evaluate its Taylor series, then obtain an approximation of what would be the integral of the expression. Or, because in your context you only need the value of the profit, an approximation is needed anyway, so just plug it in a calculator and get your answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out as I didn't realize you have to define t(x). I edited the question.

Comment: @AhmedKhan I edited my answer. I'm sorry if it's not as helpful!